# Adjective's complements

Tags: prepositions, difference

> A senior army officer is accusing the Defense Force of being far too
> **slow** to address cases of abuse.  [(ABC News)](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-03-08/abc-news/4559932)

When the adjective, slow, has its complement with to-infinitive, gerund (or participle), or prepositional phrase like below, what are their differences?

> slow **to address** cases of abuse.
>
> slow **addressing** cases of abuse.
>
> slow **in addressing** cases of abuse.

Comment: Effectively, there are no differences. The one you've quoted is the most natural usage, which is why you found it like that. But they all occur, all mean the same, and are all valid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your helpful comment to an English learner

Answer (score 3):

They are all essentially the same. The only potential difference that comes to mind is that I sometimes understand **slow to address** to mean that there is some delay or hesitancy before actually addressing the issue, whereas the other two I would only understand to mean that the actual addressing is going slowly.